# Get properties from other class (d3)

Tags: class, variables, dojo, d3.js

Hey im using the d3 plugin to work with the Collapse Tree. This is my example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Now i created 2 Widgets which are in 2 different classes. One for the tree and one for a control element. Now i want to change the properties of clicked nodes with my control element widget. So I need to get the Data(Object) from the clicked node in my other class. After I need to manipulate that data using my control widget.

"Dojo on" / "Dojo connect" are just for DOM interactions right?. 
I want to communicate between the javascript classes.

Here is my onclick function for clicking the nodes:

```
.on("click", function (d) {
    toggle(d);
    update(d)
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you need to pass a reference to the element being clicked on to another function?

Comment: yea. when i click on a node i have the  Object stored in (d). Now i want to use that one in another .js-file to work with. I want to use its content in my control widget to know which node is clicked.

Comment: Ok, so you would need to pass that object to a function from the other file that you call.

Comment: Does your control widget has global reference? Or should it be created inside `click()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom event in the tree class and handle it from the other class. First, define an event handler for the onClick event on the tree node.

```
onClick: function(evt) {
    // here comes your code
    // when you're finished, fire a custom event
    this.onNodeClicked(params);
},
onNodeClicked: function(params) {}
```

In the other class, listen for the custom event. Here I assume you create the tree widget from there. Otherwise, you can pass a reference to your tree object.

```
var tree = new MyTree();
dojo.on(tree, "onNodeClicked", this._handleOnNodeClicked);
```

Hope this helps.